# Sort inner list based on hexadecimal address in list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following list of list, where I am trying to sort inner list based on hexadecimal address.

```
a = [['abc', 10, [['3840', 'name'], ['3844', 'rank'], ['0000', 'dob']]],
     ['xyz', 20, [['2840', 'name'], ['2844', 'rank'], ['0000', 'dob']]]]
```

This is what I tried:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2][0][0], 16))
```

Output: It sorts whole list (not only inner list) based on the hexadecimal address

```
[['xyz', 20, [['2840', 'name'], ['2844', 'rank'], ['0000', 'dob']]],
 ['abc', 10, [['3840', 'name'], ['3844', 'rank'], ['0000', 'dob']]]]
```

Expected output: I need to sort only inner list as shown below

```
[['abc', 10, [['0000', 'dob'], ['3840', 'name'], ['3844', 'rank']]],
 ['xyz', 20, [['0000', 'dob'], ['2840', 'name'], ['2844', 'rank']]]]
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following, sorting the inner lists in a simple loop:

```
for *_, lst in a:
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0], 16))

a
# [['abc', 10, [['0000', 'dob'], ['3840', 'name'], ['3844', 'rank']]], 
#  ['xyz', 20, [['0000', 'dob'], ['2840', 'name'], ['2844', 'rank']]]]
```

If you are into one-liners, you can use this comprehension:

```
a[:] = [[*y, sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x[0], 16))] for *y, lst in a]
```